# How to properly use atLeastOnce method in Codeception\Util\Stub?

Tags: php, stub, codeception

I'm using codeception for testing my PHP app, and there is a method I don't know how to use. It's called `Stub::atLeastOnce()` and, like [Codeception's documentation of the Stub class](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Stub#atLeastOnce) says:

> "Checks if a method has been invoked at least one time. If the number of invocations is 0 it will throw an exception in verify."

But when I try to use it, doesn't matter that I comment the call to `User::getName()` or not, the test passes.

My user class looks like this:

```
<?php

class User {
  public function getName() {
    return 'pepito';
  }

  public function someMethod() {

  }
}
```

And my test method like this:

```
public function testStubUsage() {
    // all methods that the stub impersonates must be, at least, defined
    $user = Stub::make('User', array('getName' => Stub::atLeastOnce(function() { return 'Davert'; }), 'someMethod' => Stub::atLeastOnce('User::getName')));
    $user->getName();
}
```

So, what is the usage of that function to make the test fail if `User::getname()` is never called?

Answer (score 4):

The doc is not correct, you have to pass `$this` as third argument of `Stub::make()` for this to work properly:

```
public function testStubUsage() {
    $user = Stub::make('User', array('getName' => Stub::atLeastOnce(function() { return 'Davert';}), 'someMethod' => function() {}), $this); // <- Here
    $user->getName();
}
```

Comment: As an added bonus, passing `$this` as a third parameter doesn't help if you use the Cest format which does NOT extends `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (`Stub::doGenerateMock()`, called by `Stub::make()`, checks if the third parameter is an instance of `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` before using it).
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140295/codeception-util-stub-methods-exactly-and-once-dont-work in which OP gives a quick & dirty fix for this.